# Get the first week in a row of consecutive weeks in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have been working trying to get the first week in a row of consecutive weeks for an specific id in a DataFrame like this:

```
week     id
 1        1
 2        1
 3        1
 6        1
 7        1
 8        1
 3        2
 4        2
```

So for id 1, there's three consecutive weeks (1-3), then again three consecutive weeks (6-8), and for id 2, there's 2 (3-4). So, my desired output would be:

```
week     id   first_week
 1        1       1
 2        1       1
 3        1       1
 6        1       6
 7        1       6
 8        1       6
 3        2       3
 4        2       3
```

I was able to count the number of consecutive weeks with this:

```
df.groupby(['id',df['week'].diff(-1).ne(-1).shift().bfill().cumsum()]).transform('count')
```

But I'm not being able to find the first week (I want to construct a new id that adds in which week the streak of consecutive weeks started)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`groupby` get the `diff` , and condition assign , then just `ffill` the `nan`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id').week.diff().ne(1),'fw']=df.week
df.fw=df.fw.ffill()
df
Out[158]: 
   week  id   fw
0     1   1  1.0
1     2   1  1.0
2     3   1  1.0
3     6   1  6.0
4     7   1  6.0
5     8   1  6.0
6     3   2  3.0
7     4   2  3.0
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Do you know any resources where I can learn more about more advanced uses of `groupby` ? I'm only used to  grouping by one or more columns and then applying an aggregation function and I'd love to start understanding the other uses

Comment: @JuanC hi , https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html, those 'advance groupby ' usage is combine with others . And hope the link can help .